# Issue load webpage after basic auth android

Tags: java, android, basic-authentication

I need to load webpage after basic auth, but the sessionid in my code is not concatenated to url (I get this 10-08 10:17:27.424 20143-20143/com.example.marco.bella D/WebView: loadUrl=https://unimol.esse3.cineca.it/auth/Logon.do;jsessionid=
)...i don't know why...i show you my code!

variable `cookie` get the correct `sessionID`.

Thanks in advance!

```
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("https://unimol.esse3.cineca.it/auth/Logon.do");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    }
    HttpURLConnection httpRequest = null;
    try {
        httpRequest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    try {
        httpRequest.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {

    }
    String cookie = "";
    httpRequest.setDoInput(true);
    String authString = "user" + ":" + "pass";
    byte[] authEncBytes = android.util.Base64.encode(authString.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
    httpRequest.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    System.out.println("auth:" + "" + authStringEnc);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            cookie=cookies.get(i).toString();
        }
    }

    webView.loadUrl("https://unimol.esse3.cineca.it/auth/Logon.do;jsessionid="+cookie);
```

Comment: What's get printed into console when this line `System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());` gets executed ?

Comment: print the correct id..

Answer (score 0):

> (I get this 10-08 10:17:27.424 20143-20143/com.example.marco.bella
>   D/WebView:
>   loadUrl=https://unimol.esse3.cineca.it/auth/Logon.do;jsessionid= )...i
>   don't know why

The problem I can think of by looking only the portion you have posted here is that you are Overriding `cookie` variable inside your for loop and there is a high possibility on any iteration of `cookies`, one or more than 1 cookie exist whose value is blank.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            cookie=cookies.get(i).toString(); // This line is the culprit
}
```

You should check if the value of the cookie is null or empty.

Replace the culprit line with below line
I am using a utility of Strings class (`isNullOrEmpty`) of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library to check if value is null or empty, you can use your own implementation for this,

```
if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(cookies.get(i).toString())) {
   continue;
} else {
   cookie=cookies.get(i).toString();
}
```

Now if during iteration you get id which you confirmed that you are getting in console statement then it will definitely get loaded up.